# ERR EMPTY RESPOSNE on ajax delete request in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to delete a post with REST api endpoint. evry thing is working fine on local. but on live(000webhost server) its giving error with no response text.

```
http://mylivesite/wp-json/university/v1/nclike net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

this the js code:

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: (xhr) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', universityData.nonce);
        },
        url: universityData.root_url + '/wp-json/university/v1/nclike',
        type: 'DELETE',
        //dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
        data: {like: thisLikeBox.attr('data-likeid')},
    })
    .done((response) => {
        thisLikeBox.attr('data-exists', 'no');
        var likeCount = parseInt(thisLikeBox.find('.like-count').html(), 10);
        likeCount--;
        thisLikeBox.find('.like-count').html(likeCount);
        thisLikeBox.attr('data-likeid', '');
        console.log(response);
    })
    .fail((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

}
```

the error is pointing to this line of the main jQuery.js :

```
// Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
                xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

HELP!! :(

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? This is probably a server issue

Comment: I am simply using a free hosting to check devlopments and the server logs in 000webhost is giving only the tasks that i have renctly done but not actual errors. is there any way to check the server logs ?